# Apply data validation and formula in a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to apply data validation (based on list) and formula to calculate value in **a cell**.

*Problem:* I have to make a excel template which includes **Task**, **Task_Priority**(values:**1,2,3,4,5**) and **Task_Complexity**(values: **S,M,C,NA**).

*Rules:* (All the activities below, happen only for Task_Complexity column).

1. Task_Complexity can only have following 4 values: **S, M, C, NA**. So,I want to apply data validation on Task_Complexity column based on list. (please suggest for any other method).
2. If Task_Priority is 3,4 or 5; the Task_Complexity should automatically be updated to "NA".
3. If Task_Priority is 1 or 2; the user have to select S,M or C for Task_Complexity manually.

Please help me on this in writing formulas and validation for **same cell**. Thanks

Comment: if Task Priority is in column B, Task Complexity in column C;         I used  formula =if(b2>2,"NA", ""). But writing this formula in cells removes the data validation of cells. For Task Priorities 1 & 2, the Complexity should be displayed as S,M,C,NA. Using the above formula removes this validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, I'm not sure I understand your question!

If the Task Priority is in `B2`, put `=IF(B2>2,"NA","")` in your cell and for validation choose a range containing only S, M and C (in separate cells).

*Edit to add example:*

[image: SU607113 example]

Comment: if Task Priority is in column B, Task Complexity in column C;         I used  formula **=if(b2>2,"NA", "")**. But writing this formula in cells removes the data validation of cells. For Task Priorities 1 & 2, the Complexity should be displayed as S,M,C,NA. Using the above formula removes this validation.

Comment: Don't know if I explained the question properly. I want to keep both the formula and data validation in the same cell. But it seems if I enter formula, the data validation is removed for task_priority 1 & 2. I have MS Excel 2007 in my laptop.

Comment: in case if Priority is 1 or 2, i want the cell to display a dropdown list to select S,M,C.
If i use this formula, the cell value is replaced by **""** for priority 1 & 2.

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem. First the formula is to be applied and then the data validation.